# UCMA 5.0 vs UCMA Performance

Tags: performance, ucma, ucwa

I have developed a chatbot application using UMCA 5.0 SDK for integration with skype for business server. I was told that UCWA is more beneficial than UCMA. But, under the impression that UCWA purpose is mainly to integrate with skype for business online, I went with UCMA and everything works fine.

Now, I want to make sure that UCMA does not have performance/memory issues with when end users increases. I could not find issues as such reported on UCMA anywhere specifically but wanted to know if anyone faced performance issues with UCMA 5. And, if yes, how to solve.

Please advice the right choice between UCMA and UCWA for skype for business server integration with concurrent users around 500.

Thank you,

Comment: hi, need some pointers on building a bot using UCMA... can you help ?